# Android, Remove square border around circular progress bar

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a circular progress bar that I designed through xml. The problem is, if I set layout_width and layout_height to wrap_content, it will cut off the circle. If I set the width and height manually to "__dp" then there is a huge box around the circle which expands too much. To explain more clearly, my progress bar starts when you touch it. However, with this border around it, even if you touch next to the progress bar it will start (when it shouldn't). How can I remove this border? Thanks!

[image]

```
    <ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
    android:max="100"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
```

circle_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="7"
    android:thickness="5dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="#CCC" />

</shape>
```

circular_progress_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="7"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="5dp"
        android:useLevel="true">

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#007DD6"
            android:startColor="#007DD6"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the wrong style.

```
   style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

is meant for horizontal `ProgressBar`s. Remove the style or use one that is meant to be used for circular `ProgressBar`s like

```
style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
```

Comment: There's still a box around it if I do that.

Comment: Can you post the two drawables that you're using somewhere

Comment: Sure I added it to the question

Comment: Do you want terminate or indeterminate ProgressBar?

Comment: determinate progress bar